# How to increase VARCHAR size using grails migration

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

I have added 2 new columns `SCOMMENT` and `SURL` for table `DB_SERVER` using grails migration (liquibase)

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "syam (generated)", id: "changelog-2.3.6") {

        addColumn(tableName:"DB_SERVER"){
            column(name:"SCOMMENT", type:"VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)"){
                    constraints(nullable: "true")
                }
        }

        addColumn(tableName:"DB_SERVER"){
            column(name:"SURL", type:"VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)"){
                    constraints(nullable: "true")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially I defined `SCOMMENT` and `SURL` as of 255 characters length. In the next version, I'm trying to increase the character length to 1024 using `modifyColumn` as below

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "syam (generated)", id: "changelog-2.3.7") {
        // Increase maximum length of characters for scomment field in DbServer
        modifyDataType(columnName:"SCOMMENT", tableName:"DB_SERVER", newDataType="VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR)")

        //Increase the maximum length of characters for surl field in DbServer
        modifyDataType(columnName:"SURL", tableName:"DB_SERVER", newDataType="VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR)")
    }
}
```

When I tried to migrate, I get the following error

```
Error 2014-12-08 13:11:28,086 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     2 changes have validation failures
          newDataType is required, changelog-2.3.7.groovy::changelog-2.3.7::syam(generated)::(Checksum: 3:04f74b0209f64ad261e4a864fcc3c43c)
Message: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     2 changes have validation failures
          newDataType is required, changelog-2.3.7.groovy::changelog-2.3.7::syam (generated)::(Checksum: 3:04f74b0209f64ad261e4a864fcc3c43c)
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
```

How could the length of characters be changed for `SCOMMENT` and `SURL`?

Comment: That's probably close, but you should remove the "CHAR", right? Shouldn't it just be VARCHAR2(1024)? The message seems be saying you didn't specify the type, but that's probably because it's an unexpected format. Is that valid when you do this by hand in a client?

Comment: Tried without "CHAR" and got the same error again. I usually generate the _changelog_ by `dbm-gorm-diff`. _changelog-2.3.6_ (code in the first block) is the exact code generated. Yes, modifying by hand on client working fine.

Comment: I'm using grails **version 2.2.4** and **database-migration-1.3.2**. Is it a problem with the old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a Liquibase error, not a database error. Liquibase is not seeing the newDataType attribute and so throwing a validation error but you are setting it. I'm able to run a similar changeSet with standard liquibase and xml or json so it may be a problem with the grails DSL. It may be worth opening an issue with them.

You can always fall back to the "sql" command and just pass the ALTER TABLE statement directly as well if there is a problem with the grails parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the same, copied your code and got the same error. I found out that you had a typo: you have to replace '=' with ':' in "newDataType=...". Then, I had no error with that fix.

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted has a typo.  You have an equals sign where you should have a colon:

Change

```
modifyDataType(columnName:"SCOMMENT", tableName:"DB_SERVER", newDataType="VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR)")
```

To

```
modifyDataType(columnName:"SCOMMENT", tableName:"DB_SERVER", newDataType:"VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the database sql dialect of the DB you are using the change set syntax varies.
With MySQL GORM:

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author: "kujalpe (manual)", id: "1493972667393-1") {
        comment{'BUG-1 Increase SCOMMENT column size in DB_SERVER table'}
        modifyDataType(tableName: "DB_SERVER", columnName: "SCOMMENT", newDataType: "varchar(1024)")
    }
}
```